# Retrieve text from a RemoteViews Object

Tags: android, remoteview

I need to retrieve some text from a `RemoteViews` object. It is possible for me to get the LayoutId, but I have no idea how to retrieve text from a `TextView` that is in this `RemoteView` (namely a notification).

Also the `RemoteView` only contains setters, but no getters, so I guess I have to use the LayoutId (somehow).

Can you help me with that? Thanks!

**/edit:** The reason why I am asking this, is because I have an `AccessibilityService` that retrieves the notification. Therefore this is the only way of retrieving the value.

**/edit2:** I use this code for receiving the notification:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
        List<CharSequence> notificationList = event.getText();
        for (int i = 0; i < notificationList.size(); i++) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), notificationList.get(i), 1).show();
        }
        if (!(parcel instanceof Notification)) {
            return;
        }
        final Notification notification = (Notification) parcel;
        doMoreStuff();

    }
}
```

With the `notification` object I have access to a `RemoteViews` (`notification.contentView`) and to a `PendingIntent` (`notification.contentIntent`).
To get the layoutId, I can call `contentView.getLayoutId()`

Comment: It would probably be better to save the information somewhere (`SharedPreferences`, etc), and then have both the `RemoteViews` and your other code access the information from there.

Comment: Well, I am using a `AccessibilityService` for retrieving the notification, so I cannot simply store the value somewhere, because my application did not create the notification ;-)

Comment: How do you get the layout id? Can you post the code that receives the notifcation?

Comment: Hmm, not sure you can. I thought that maybe the Notification would contain a reference to the Intent that caused it (and its data), but it doesn't seem to. Don't think you can retrieve the data from the RemoteViews object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [Extract notification text from parcelable, contentView or contentIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent) :

```
Notification notification = (Notification) event.getParcelableData();
RemoteViews views = notification.contentView;
Class secretClass = views.getClass();

try {
    Map<Integer, String> text = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    Field outerFields[] = secretClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < outerFields.length; i++) {
        if (!outerFields[i].getName().equals("mActions")) continue;

        outerFields[i].setAccessible(true);

        ArrayList<Object> actions = (ArrayList<Object>) outerFields[i]
        .get(views);
        for (Object action : actions) {
            Field innerFields[] = action.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

            Object value = null;
            Integer type = null;
            Integer viewId = null;
            for (Field field : innerFields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.getName().equals("value")) {
                    value = field.get(action);
                } else if (field.getName().equals("type")) {
                    type = field.getInt(action);
                } else if (field.getName().equals("viewId")) {
                    viewId = field.getInt(action);
                }
            }

            if (type == 9 || type == 10) {
                text.put(viewId, value.toString());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("title is: " + text.get(16908310));
        System.out.println("info is: " + text.get(16909082));
        System.out.println("text is: " + text.get(16908358));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: notification.contentView its deprecated is there any alternative solution for extracting data from  AccessibilityEvent object please help me.

Answer (score 9):

I proposed a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent) that also uses reflection to solve the problem, but in a more approachable fashion.  This is my solution. In this context, the RemoteViews came from a Notification, so the first three lines can probably be ignored if you already have access to the RemoteViews object. The link on the page provides a much more detailed explanation of what is actually going on. I hope this will help anyone with a similar problem.

```
public static List<String> getText(Notification notification)
{
    // We have to extract the information from the view
    RemoteViews        views = notification.bigContentView;
    if (views == null) views = notification.contentView;
    if (views == null) return null;

    // Use reflection to examine the m_actions member of the given RemoteViews object.
    // It's not pretty, but it works.
    List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        Field field = views.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActions");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Parcelable> actions = (ArrayList<Parcelable>) field.get(views);

        // Find the setText() and setTime() reflection actions
        for (Parcelable p : actions)
        {
            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            p.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
            parcel.setDataPosition(0);

            // The tag tells which type of action it is (2 is ReflectionAction, from the source)
            int tag = parcel.readInt();
            if (tag != 2) continue;

            // View ID
            parcel.readInt();

            String methodName = parcel.readString();
            if (methodName == null) continue;

            // Save strings
            else if (methodName.equals("setText"))
            {
                // Parameter type (10 = Character Sequence)
                parcel.readInt();

                // Store the actual string
                String t = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel).toString().trim();
                text.add(t);
            }

            // Save times. Comment this section out if the notification time isn't important
            else if (methodName.equals("setTime"))
            {
                // Parameter type (5 = Long)
                parcel.readInt();

                String t = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(new Date(parcel.readLong()));
                text.add(t);
            }

            parcel.recycle();
        }
    }

    // It's not usually good style to do this, but then again, neither is the use of reflection...
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("NotificationClassifier", e.toString());
    }

    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969019/retrieve-text-from-textbox-in-android-widget) says:

> ... App widgets are **write-only**: you can push data to them, but you
>   cannot read them.      Instead, when you update your app widget with
>   new text, you will need to store that text somewhere, perhaps in a
>   file.

His answer seems to be logical.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting on Android 19+, you can use the following code for getting title/text from a Notification object without using any private APIs.

```
Notification noty = ...;
Bundle extras = noty.extras;
if (extras != null) {
  String title = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
  String text = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
}
```