# Get Notification Text under GB

Tags: android, notifications

Is there a way to get the layout ID of a TextView in android? Specifically I want to get the ID (or better the Text) from the TextView 3 in this Image:

[image]

I found some code on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent) but it does not work under GB. Is there a way to get the text under GB?

Answer (score 1):

This text is inside a notification, which is created by some other app, and handled by the system.  Getting the text is not trivial, for security reasons, but it may be possible using an accessibility service (http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html).

Comment: Okay thanks for that. In an `AccessibilityService` I get an `AccessibilityEvent` in `onAccessibilityEvent`. Do you have any idea how I can get the text from this object?

Comment: Sorry I've never tried myself, I just know that's the way some apps can achieve this.