# view.reapply of RemoteView of bigContentView notification crashing

Tags: android, android-notifications, layout-inflater, android-remoteview

I am attempting to build an app to post notifications to my smartwatch. I found a great notify example application, which I have modified for my testing and it works as expected. I found that the extended information I need to display is in the RemoteViews bigContentView.  I found a program called Botification, which is able to inflate the view I am looking for.  It works as expected in his application.  I am trying to marry his methods to mine, and having no luck.  I also found some source for Notify Me!, which is using the same type method for pulling the notification remote view.

This is my first real Android app, and I am new to Java.  I have been working this for about a month now and have learned a TON from posts on this site and browsing the web.  I went through the Lynda.com courses for Java Essentials and Android Essentials.  Also found this useful to me, being new to Java and having only a little background in C++ :http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/index.html.

Some sources of information I have used:
[Extract notification text from parcelable, contentView or contentIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent) and http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html

Any help would be appreciated.  The Botification application uses a handler and a different way to process onPosted requests, which makes me wonder if that is my problem.  Any documentation or tutorials to fatten my brain would be welcome.

I am including the sections of the code that use this remote view functionality and hopefully enough to where it makes sense on how I am making it work.

MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private TextView txtView;
private NotificationReceiver nReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    nReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.example.snotify.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER");
    registerReceiver(nReceiver,filter);
}
```

nlservice.java
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

```
private String TAG = "NLService";
private NLServiceReceiver nlreceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    nlreceiver = new NLServiceReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.example.snotify.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE");
    registerReceiver(nlreceiver,filter);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(nlreceiver);
}


@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Notification n = sbn.getNotification();
    Log.i(TAG,"!!!onNotificationPosted");
    Log.i(TAG,"ID :" + sbn.getId() + "Ticker:" + n.tickerText + "Pkg:" + sbn.getPackageName());
    String text = NotiCrunch.extractTextFromNotification(NLService.this, n);
    String description = "";
    if (n.tickerText != null) {
        description = n.tickerText.toString();
    }
    Intent i = new  Intent("com.example.snotify.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER");
    i.putExtra("notification_event","Notification Posted\nPackage:" + sbn.getPackageName() + "\nID:" + sbn.getId() 
            + "\nText:" + text
            + "\nTag:" + sbn.getTag() + "\nTicker:" + description + "\n\n");
    sendBroadcast(i);

}
```

noticrunch.java

public class NotiCrunch {

```
private static String TAG = "NotiCrunch";
private static final int TIMESTAMPID = 16908388;

private static void extractViewType(ArrayList<View> outViews, Class<TextView> viewtype, View source) {
    if (ViewGroup.class.isInstance(source)) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) source;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            extractViewType(outViews, viewtype, vg.getChildAt(i));

        }
    } else if(viewtype.isInstance(source)) {
        outViews.add(source);
    }
}

public static String extractTextFromNotification(Service service, Notification notification) {
    ArrayList<String> result = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        result = extractTextFromNotification(service, notification.bigContentView);
        Log.d(TAG, "It tried Big View");
        Log.d(TAG, "Ticker:" + notification.tickerText);
    }
    if (result == null) {
        result = extractTextFromNotification(service, notification.contentView);
        Log.d(TAG, "It tried little view");
    }
    if (result == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "It is returning null");
        return "";
    }
    return TextUtils.join("\n", result);

}

private static ArrayList<String> extractTextFromNotification(Service service, RemoteViews view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) service.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (view == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial view is Empty");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        ViewGroup localView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(view.getLayoutId(), null);
        view.reapply(service.getApplicationContext(), localView);
        ArrayList<View> outViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        extractViewType(outViews, TextView.class, localView);
        for (View  ttv: outViews) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) ttv;
            String txt = tv.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(txt) && tv.getId() != TIMESTAMPID) {
                result.add(txt);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FAILED to load notification! " + e.toString());
        Log.wtf(TAG, e);
        return null;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Return result" + result);
    return result;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code crashing? I don't see a call to reapply anywhere.

Comment: view.reapply(service.getApplicationContext(), localView); is in the noticrunch.java in the try/catch loop.  Thank you for looking.

Comment: I didn't see the code box was scrolled. Wow, this code looks like it's making a lot of assumptions and trusting a lot of what it's finding. You're going to have to do a lot of trial and error to find the answer here, but to keep the reapply call from crashing, I'd suggest taking a peek at the RemoteView docs, reapply looks like it is expected to be called after an apply call (which I don't see), and reapply says it can throw. I'd start by changing the reapply to an apply, if you even need that at all (do you?)

Comment: All of the examples I have seen on this remoteview do a reapply.  I can't say that I understand why.  I am still learning.  I am not sure why this code works elsewhere, but I assume it is the way I am calling everything.  I might need a few more lightbulbs to light in my head.