# Getting Data from Notification

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I am wiriting application and I don't know how to get data from Notification. I have NotificationListenerService (like [this](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html)) and when new Notification occurs I recieve StatusBarNotification object. Anyone know how to take Title and Content of notification from this object (in tutorial is only tickerText)?

Comment: I found similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent), but answer isn't too good and maybe anyone knows simpler way todo it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fount simple way to do it, but it is available on android 19+ (KitKat 4.4.2):

If you want for example title of Notification, you can use something like this:

```
String title = sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
```

There is more information in extras, like text, prgress, time etc. - details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)

sbn object is StatusBarNotification class object (the way how to reach this you can find in [this tutorial](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html)

If you need to do it on earlier version of Android you have to try any answer from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent).