# Facebook messenger accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility, facebook-messenger, android-a11y

I am writing an accessibility app that helps users navigate on android using a mixture of voice controls and controls provided via external aiding tools. It uses MonkeyTalk Java API to do the heavier work.
To help the user about what is happening we use an accessibility service as well, which reads notification so the user can take action faster.

I've been informed that they get no audio cue when a message arrives on facebook messenger, and checking logs what I see is:

```
D/NotificationService(2665): package com.facebook.orcaText: []
```

and `event.getText().size()` returns 0 (on AccessibilityEvent event).
Right now they have to open the app and get the text read to them, which is 2 voice commands more...
I get all the other notifications correctly. I tried looking for documentation from facebook about their stance on accessibility but I found nothing.
Is there any way to get the text from their notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to see if it works with Facebook messenger notifications. And even if this does work, I would suggest that you wait for a better solution.

From API 19 and above, `Notification` objects carry bundled `extras` - the inputs passed to `Notification.Builder` when the `Notification` was first created. So, information such as the `title`, `context`, `summary` etc. can be extracted from this `Bundle` using keys of form `Notification.EXTRAS_XXXX`. The keys can be found here: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html).

In the overriden `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)` method:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Parcelable data = event.getParcelableData();

    if (data != null && data instanceof Notification) {
        Log.i("", "We have a notification to parse");

        Notification notification = (Notification) data;

        // For API 19 and above, `Notifications` carry an `extras` bundle with them
        // From this bundle, you can extract info such as:

        //      `EXTRA_TITLE`     -  as supplied to setContentTitle(CharSequence)
        //      `EXTRA_TEXT `     -  as supplied to setContentText(CharSequence)
        //      `EXTRA_INFO_TEXT` -  as supplied to setContentInfo(CharSequence)
        //      ... more at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

        Bundle b = noti.extras;
        Log.i("Notification", "Title: " + b.get(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE));
        Log.i("Notification", "Text: " + b.get(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT));
        Log.i("Notification", "Info Text: " + b.get(Notification.EXTRA_INFO_TEXT));

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // For API 18 and under:

        // Pass `notification` to a method that parses a Notification object - See link below

        List<String> notificationText = extractTextFromNotification(notification);
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

`extractTextFromNotification(Notification)` can be a method from here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent). Needless to say that this is a workaround, and will require quite a bit of testing to ensure that it works as required.

Comment: Right now we use api19+, so it really is okay. In the future we'll support older phones, maybe then I'll use the inflate view trick, I kinda liked that!

Comment: The extra fields proved to work just perfect! I am using it now for the rest of the notification messages as well.Thank you!

Comment: @sokie `I am using it now for the rest of the notification messages as well.` Awesome! Didn't think of recommending you to do that.

Comment: I am still talking about api 19+ tough.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `getActiveNotifications` method of `NotificationListenerService` to get an array of notifications that are visible to current user.
The result is an `StatusBarNotification` array, So you can read the PackageName with `getPackageName` and if it matches with that you are looking for, then get the notification content from that object (with `getNotification`)...

You can extend `NotificationListenerService` class and register it as a service:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
      android:label="@string/service_name"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
 </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also you can implement `onNotificationPosted` method to get notifications and even cancel notifications with `cancelNotification` method.

An example of using this service:
https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example

**Note**:
User must enable notification permission from "Settings > Security > Notification access".
You can open that setting with:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This still returns empty for facebook messenger.

Comment: Did you try this code with facebook messenger? I have no problem accessing any other notification, the only one that returns empty is facebook messenger.