# Read content from notification parcelable objects for consequent notification

Tags: android, notifications, whatsapp

I am trying to build Whatsapp Notification filtering app, where I monitor all notification from Whatsapp and remove messages as per filtering policy.

I can fetch message content using below link code 
[Extract notification text from parcelable, contentView or contentIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent) for first message only

but the problem is I can fetch only first message, if user does not read first message then second message onwards I get only "2 messages from sender" instead of actual message.

NOTE: I am getting

android.text = actual message for first message but its null from second message/notification onwards
android.title = sender
android.summaryText = "n new messages"

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing same problem @ghmulchandani . Did you got solution for this ?

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper, does it solve your problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, finally after few hours of googling I design a code which does work for me.

```
Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    CharSequence[] lines = extras.getCharSequenceArray(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);
    JSONArray s = new JSONArray();
    for (CharSequence msg : lines) {
                    msg = removeSpaces(msg);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
                        s.put(msg.toString());
                    }
                }
    private static String removeSpaces(@Nullable CharSequence cs) {
            if (cs == null)
                return null;
            String string = cs instanceof String ? (String) cs : cs.toString();
            return string.replaceAll("(\\s+$|^\\s+)", "").replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
        }
```

here JSONArray s contains all messages that I want

Comment: I will give it a try & will give my feedback for sure.

Comment: can you please explain what the extras in your first line,can you please provide full code.i was also try and can able to get first message only.

Comment: @Ravi, I just edited the code for you. you need to put this code in onNotificationPosted of NotificationListenerService

Comment: The final string contains the data is             String string = cs instanceof String ? (String) cs : cs.toString(); ?

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper and did you :) ?