# Get Notification Message using accessibilityservice android

Tags: android, notifications, accessibilityservice

In My android app I want to show history of notification, so I want to capture all notifications title and message.
I am using accessibilityservice and able to fetch title using parcelable data but not get original message text.

If you have any ideal please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I found similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292032/extract-notification-text-from-parcelable-contentview-or-contentintent)

another way is -

```
 Parcelable data = event.getParcelableData();
                if (data instanceof Notification) {
                    Log.d("Tortuga","Recieved notification");
                    Notification notification = (Notification) data;
                    Log.d("Tortuga","ticker: " + notification.tickerText);
                    Log.d("Tortuga","icon: " + notification.icon);
                    Log.d("Tortuga", "notification: "+event.getText());
```

hope it will give help in finding your solution.